# Using mask to show/hide a view with animation

Tags: ios, ios8, calayer, mask, bounds

I am trying to use a mask to hide and show a view, but I cannot get it work correctly for some reason.

I am really confused about whether I should animate the frame/bounds/path of the mask.

Here is my code to show a view on a button action "GO":

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{

        self.testView.layer.mask.bounds = self.testView.layer.bounds;
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.testView.bounds.size.width, 0);
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, NULL);

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = path;

    self.testView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
    self.testView.layer.mask.bounds = rect;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, always follow the "Create Rule", i.e. if you call a Core Graphics function with either "Copy" or "Create" in the name, you're responsible for releasing the object. If you ran this through the static analyzer (shift+command+B or choose "Analyze" from Xcode's "Product" menu), it would have brought this to your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the `bounds` of the mask, but not the `path`. You really need to change the `path` of the `mask`. You theoretically can do that with `CABasicAnimation`, but I personally find that pretty flaky when animating paths (especially those of a mask).

If you can, I'd retire the mask altogether and just set the frame of the  `testView` so that it's not visible (e.g. height of zero) and then animate the changing of that frame with the block-based `UIView` `animateWithDuration`. (Note, if using auto layout, then you might animate the `setNeedsLayout` having changed the constraints).

If you really need to use the `CAShapeLayer` mask, you can try the `CABAsicAnimation` with `animateWithKeyPath` of the `path` key on the mask `CAShapeLayer`.

Personally, when animating the change of a path, I'd use a display link, e.g. something like:

```
- (IBAction)didTapButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [AnimationDisplayLink animateWithDuration:3.0 animationHandler:^(CGFloat percent) {
        self.mask.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.testView.bounds.size.width, self.testView.bounds.size.height * percent)].CGPath;
    } completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Where my `AnimationDisplayLink` is defined as follows:

```
@interface AnimationDisplayLink : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat animationDuration;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^animationHandler)(CGFloat percent);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^completionHandler)();
@end

@interface AnimationDisplayLink ()
@property (nonatomic) CFAbsoluteTime startTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@end

@implementation AnimationDisplayLink

+ (instancetype)animateWithDuration:(CGFloat)duration animationHandler:(void (^)(CGFloat percent))animationHandler completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
    AnimationDisplayLink *handler = [[self alloc] init];

    handler.animationDuration = duration;
    handler.animationHandler  = animationHandler;
    handler.completionHandler = completionHandler;

    [handler startAnimation];

    return handler;
}

- (void)startAnimation {
    self.startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)stopAnimation {
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink {
    CGFloat elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.startTime;
    CGFloat percent = elapsed / self.animationDuration;

    if (percent >= 1.0) {
        [self stopAnimation];
        if (self.animationHandler)  self.animationHandler(1.0);
        if (self.completionHandler) self.completionHandler();
    } else {
        if (self.animationHandler)  self.animationHandler(percent);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! Animated the path of the mask and it worked. BTW, should I set animation's removedOnCompletion to NO and fillMode to kCAFillModeForwards in order it to stay in the final animation state?

Comment: If using `CABasicAnimation`, then, yes, you can do that. Or, right before then animation, set the path to the final path, that way, when the animation is removed, if will use whatever it was immediately before the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of Rob's answer

```
import UIKit

typealias PercentBasedAnimationHandler = ((_ percent: CGFloat) -> Void)
typealias AnimationCompletionHandler = (() -> Void)

class AnimationDisplayLink: NSObject {
var animationDuration: CGFloat = 0.3

var animationHandler: PercentBasedAnimationHandler!
var completionHandler: AnimationCompletionHandler!

var startTime: CFAbsoluteTime!

var displayLink: CADisplayLink!

static func animateWith(duration: CGFloat, animationHanlder: @escaping PercentBasedAnimationHandler, completionHandler: @escaping AnimationCompletionHandler) -> AnimationDisplayLink {

    let handler = AnimationDisplayLink()
    handler.animationDuration = duration
    handler.animationHandler = animationHanlder
    handler.completionHandler = completionHandler
    handler.startAnimation()

    return handler
}

func startAnimation() {
    self.startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    self.displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(hanldeDisplayLink(displayLink:)))
    self.displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: .commonModes)
}

func stopAnimation() {
    self.displayLink.invalidate()
    self.displayLink = nil
}

@objc func hanldeDisplayLink(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    let elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.startTime
    let percent = CGFloat(elapsed) / animationDuration

    if percent >= 1.0 {
        stopAnimation()
        self.animationHandler(1.0)
        self.completionHandler()
    } else {
        self.animationHandler(percent)
    }
}
}
```